# Check if domain registration has lapsed and been offered publicly in the past

Tags: domains, whois

Im trying to tell if a currently registered doamin, registration has lapsed in the past. When i look at the Whois it tells me that :

```
Expires On August 25, 2016
Registered On August 25, 1999
Updated On October 22, 2015
```

I got this data from http://who.is is there a way i can tell if in October 22, 2015 the domain was renewed or if it had lapsed become public and then re registered ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell a domain's history just by looking at the Whois record - that is just a current snapshot. However, there are some 3rd party services (eg. [domaintools.com](http://research.domaintools.com/research/whois-history/) - not free) that monitor and report on this information.

The "Updated" date is simply when the Whois record was last updated. *Anything* could have been updated.

By coincidence, one of my domains reports very similar dates:

```
Expiry date:   18-Aug-2016
Registered on: 18-Aug-2000
Last updated:  06-Oct-2015
```

I've had this domain since it was first registered. It has never expired. However, the information (Registrar, Nameservers and address information) has been updated several times over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Well, put a common sense logic in your question.

> No, there's no way you can tell if domain was renewed.

However...

when someone updates a domain information it doesn't mean that it automaticly becomes renewed.

So in this example:

You are registering domain on 1 year period. 
This means means that domain is renewed `August 26, 2015` and someone updated informations on domain on `Updated On October 22, 2015`

Comment: I was wandering about the difference between August and October but concluded that someone might have been buying the domain in 1 or 2 year blocks, but then let it run through its grace expiration period thus the extra months.