# top-level domain registration: does "updating" imply a license extension (Whois report)?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains, whois, registration, licenses

I created a blog and I want to purchase a second level **domain**, that's to say I want to move from *domain*.altervista.org to -> *domain*.com.

I would like to register that domain with the **.com extension** but it is already registered.

By doing a research on **Whois** I found out that the site was created on may 2010 and expires on may 2016, and it was updated on September 2015 (The owner put it on sale for 1000 dollars), but I wonder if the "update" does mean that the license has been extended or if it does refer to something else.

In any case I'm considering waiting to have the .com extension available again for free.

So ->

*- Given the dates provided by Whois, do they mean that the **domain**.com will be **available again** on may or should I wait more?*

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89411/check-if-domain-registration-has-lapsed-and-been-offered-publicly-in-the-past/89493#89493

Comment: We get questions like this fairly often where someone wants a domain name that is already registered. Most of the time they are looking for a loop-hole to challenge the ownership of the domain, but this time, you come with a valid question. However, in part, the result ends up being the same. If a domain name is registered and especially if they want serious money for it, I would not suggest waiting. It never seems to work out. It can take a while, but I am sure a domain name you will like much better will come to mind that IS available. Do yourself a favor and just let it go.